# Trying to filter by date in OpenSearch with day, month, year (looking to convert painless script in java)

Tags: java, elasticsearch, opensearch, elasticsearch-painless

```
            "filter" : [
                {
          "bool" : {
            "must" : [
              {
              "script": {
      "script": """
         int day ;
         int month ;
         int year;
         
      if ( (int) doc['decisionDate.decisionDay'].size() > 0 && (int) doc['decisionDate.decisionMonth'].size() > 0  && (int) doc['decisionDate.decisionYear'].size() > 0) {

      day = (int) doc['decisionDate.decisionDay'].value;
      month = (int) doc['decisionDate.decisionMonth'].value;
      year = (int) doc['decisionDate.decisionYear'].value;

    return
      ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(ZonedDateTime.of(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of('Z')), 
      ZonedDateTime.of(2022, 12, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of('Z'))) > 0 && 
      ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(ZonedDateTime.of(2011, 03, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of('Z')), 
      ZonedDateTime.of( year,  month, day, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of('Z'))) > 0 ; } """
              
    }
            }
            ]
          }
                }
              ]
```

above code is the date filter with day, month, year in OpenSearch, I am trying to convert it into Script in java. I have no idea how it convert in java

tried to use plugin 'org.codelibs.fess:fess:14.4.0'

```
    final SearchEngineClient searchEngineClient = ComponentUtil.getSearchEngineClient();
    final FessConfig fessConfig = ComponentUtil.getFessConfig();
    final LabelTypeHelper labelTypeHelper = ComponentUtil.getLabelTypeHelper();
    final LanguageHelper languageHelper = ComponentUtil.getLanguageHelper();


    Script script = ComponentUtil.getLanguageHelper().createScript("here i need add the above (painless script), st);
```

Comment: found a solution using stored script

                "filter" : [{
                  
                 "script": {
                   "script": {
 "id" : "date_filter_script",
         "params": {
          "year_end": 2022,
          "month_end" : 12,
          "day_end" : 13,
          "year_start": 2011,
          "month_start" : 3,
          "day_start" : 30
        }
                   }     
        }
                  
                }
                  ]

Answer (score 0):

This is stored script in opensearch

POST /_scripts/date_filter_script
{

```
             "script": {    
                "lang" : "painless",
      "source": """
         int day ;
         int month ;
         int year;
         
      if ( (int) doc['decisionDate.decisionDay'].size() != 0 ) {
      day = (int) doc['decisionDate.decisionDay'].value;
      }
   
      if ( (int) doc['decisionDate.decisionMonth'].size() != 0 ) {
      month = (int) doc['decisionDate.decisionMonth'].value;
      }
      
         if ( (int) doc['decisionDate.decisionYear'].size() != 0 ) {
      year = (int) doc['decisionDate.decisionYear'].value;
      }
   

      if (day >= 1 && month >= 1 && year >= 1) {
        return
      ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(ZonedDateTime.of(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of('Z')), ZonedDateTime.of(params.year_end, params.month_end, params.day_end, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of('Z'))) > 0 && ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(ZonedDateTime.of(params.year_start, params.month_start, params.day_start, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of('Z')), ZonedDateTime.of( year,  month, day, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of('Z'))) > 0 ; } """
              
    }
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).